# Autolisp, difference of two dxf files

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin

I want to get the difference of two dxf files and want to save it in third file. I want to set the limitation also. If my text shifts upto certain units , it shouldn't be shown in difference.
'DWG diff' partially does the job. It is not flexible. I cann't set limits and cann't save the diff. Does someone knows better software or Autolisp.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention whether you want to see a comprehensive graphical difference or if you are just looking for "text shifts". A DXF file is a text file so you can diff it with anything that diffs text. You could then check the diff (export a patch file, perhaps) for "text shits".

Comment: I want to get comprehensive graphical difference.

Comment: That is non-trivial. Here is an existing app that compares 2 DWG files (you need AutoCAD to run it in) http://apps.exchange.autodesk.com/ACD/en/Detail/Index?id=appstore.exchange.autodesk.com%3adwgcompare%3aen

Note it won't save the diff result as a new DWG.